# ScriptSharp indexer with generics

Tags: script#

I have a class that needs a generic indexer, however script# doesn't compile this.

```
[Imported]
public class SomeCollection<T>
{
    [IntrinsicProperty]
    public T this[int index] 
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { }
    }
}
```

I want the 'SomeCollection' class to be a javascript Array when script# compiles it down. I only want this class + indexer with generics to make it easier when I write c# to get proper intellisense for objects.

How do I get script# to compile the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now you'll have to write the above class in an import library, i.e. it is not just an imported type, but a type that isn't compiled by script#. Instead it is only compiled by the c# compiler, and script# simply imports the type definitions.

That said, why not just use List<T>, or T[]? Is it because you only want an indexer and no other methods?

Comment: Thanks Nikhil, I don't want to use List<T> or T[] because if I use them I'll need to include mscorlib.js, there is a collision between Script# mscorlib.js and another application I'm working with so I have to stick to out of the box js syntax.

Comment: You should see the new ss.js - it uses the amd pattern, so no added globals, and also no extensions on any existing script objects.

Comment: Cool, I'll check it out. Hopefully you'll get a chance to update nuget and VS Extensions Gallery to 0.8, currently they are on 7.5.1.